# Function not found error in zoom-master plugin

Tags: jquery, zooming

I have use zoom-master plugin in my code for image zoom.

My code is

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery.zoom.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log($('#ex1').length);
        $('#ex1').zoom(); 
    });
</script>
```

My html code is

```
<span class='zoom' id='ex1'>
      <img src="admin/uploaded_image/<?php echo $imagee;?>" width="265" height="260" id='jack' />
</span>
```

But I get a JavaScript error

```
> TypeError: $(...).zoom is not a function [Break On This Error]    
> 
> $('#ex1').zoom();
```

What is the wrong in this code?

Comment: [Doesn't seem to be a problem with the code itself](http://jsfiddle.net/DQfGz/), make sure that the plugin path is right

Comment: Firebug show the plugin path is loaded.